# Date period for has_table key

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have this schema

```
-- Create tables section -----------------------------------------

-- Table t1
CREATE TABLE "t1"(
"id" Serial NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ("id");

-- Table t2
CREATE TABLE "t2"(
"id" Serial NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ("id");

-- Table t1_has_t2
CREATE TABLE "t1_has_t2"(
"t1_id" Integer NOT NULL,
"t2_id" Integer NOT NULL,
"d_start" Date,
"d_end" Date,
PRIMARY KEY ("t1_id","t2_id"),
FOREIGN KEY ("t1_id") REFERENCES "t1" ("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
FOREIGN KEY ("t2_id") REFERENCES "t2" ("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

I need to use the table "t1_has_t2" for save t1 or t2 periods. For example, I want to save this record in table "t1_has_t2":

```
+-------+-------+------------+------------+
| t1_id | t2_id | d_start    | d_end      |
+-------+-------+------------+------------+
| 1     | 1     | 01-01-2016 | 31-01-2016 |
+-------+-------+------------+------------+
| 1     | 1     | 01-02-2016 | 31-12-9999 |
+-------+-------+------------+------------+
```

I don't know how I can do to my database can add another record with the same ids, if date period are different.

Comment: Your primary key is what is restricting the table to only one of each id pair, you need to modify it to allow what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the primary key in table `t1_has_t2` only includes `t1_id` and `t2_id`. You should also include the two remaining columns in the primary key to make this work.

Incidentally, when using two dates as you do, you had better use a [`daterange`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html) column because then you can easily check for overlaps using an [`EXCLUDE` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html) with the [`&&` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html).

Comment: Use daterange would be perfect, but i using PostgreSQL 9.1. In this versión doesn't exist daterange data type. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html